# Place a div at center of another with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've a personal project to learn more about HTML/CSS/JS.
But I got a problem with it.

I have two divs in my `<body>`, each one with 2 circular concentric div. One is placed on the center of the area, the other one not.

```
<div id="sphaea_bloc">   
    <div id="actor" class="actor_locked">
        <div class="actor_extern_locked"> </div>
        <div class="actor_intern_locked"> </div>
      </div>

      <div id="lock" class="lock_locked">
        <div class="lock_extern_locked"> </div>       
        <div class="lock_intern_locked"> </div>
      </div>    
</div>
```

The base placement is good.

The second step is to add drag'n'drop with JQuery, and it works fine. The aim is to drop the little div into the bigger div.
When it fails, it correctly returns at a base position.
But now, when the drop is good, I want to place with JQuery the little div in to center of the bigger div (making 4 circles concentric).

I searched for a long time but I didn't manage to do it without the problem : I've always a little offset between my 2 divs... And I'm not able to understand why.

Here is the fiddlejs link : 
[FiddleJS link](https://jsfiddle.net/AeldredOni/8spbvqcu/)

Someone can help me to find the problem, and why my little div is always inside the bigger but with an offset ?

Thanks in advance !
AeldredOni

Comment: You can't center an element when you set its `display` attr `inline-block`

Comment: I tried with many values for it, but still the same issue :/

Comment: can u use position absolute for small div?

Comment: Yeah, but i tried it too. Maybe forgetting something (i think), i've not real restriction, because in my project, all "size" properties will be in separated css for laarge/medium screens !

Comment: do you mean you have different with and height for different screens?

Comment: Yeah, for the end of the project, but in a first time, only on my comptuer screen, it's enough !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have did like below, and its working, it will be centered even if you change with and height of divs:

```
.actor_locked {
  position:absolute;
  left:-9999px;
  right:-9999px;
  top:-9999px;
  bottom:-9999px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xga3dzfm/1/

Comment: Thanks i'll try this this evenning, if it works it's really what i needed ! Same for the next step, animate width and height of the little div !
Thanks a lot !

Comment: i hope it helps you :)

Comment: Just at the moment ^^
I tried by adding a jquery command when the drop is in the lock with :

$('#actor').css({"position": "aboslute", "left":"-9999px", "right":"-9999px",
                        "top":"-9999px", "bottom":"-9999px", "display":"block"});

But now the actor just return to the normal position, even if the correct drop is detected ...

Comment: i have created another jsfiddle link, please take a look at it
http://jsfiddle.net/xga3dzfm/1/

Comment: Thanks, It's exactly what i want to do !! :) 
So, have to append the actor to the lock, like sayin "actor is now child of lock" right ? 
Many thank :) !!